# How to make android action bar title center aligned?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, center

I tried my own Custom Action bar for getting action bar title centered on the middle. It worked. However, after I added the options menu in Action bar, the title again shifted to the left. What should I do in order to get the title centered on the middle of the action bar?
my code is:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);    
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```

and my layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/apptitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Can you post your code what you tried to center the title?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23841756/896322 here maybe you can find solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center align the ActionBar title in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am sure, you are using the below to set your custom theme.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```

If not, then please add the first line. And the text in your custom layout is centered. (Gravity = Center)

Also I found a similar link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244411/center-align-title-in-action-bar-using-styles-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244411/center-align-title-in-action-bar-using-styles-in-android). Hope this helps.

Try this out as well.

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by *not* showing the title of
the activity, and instead using a customView as you suggested. The key
that I missed for a while was you must use the setCustomView(View,
ActionVar.LayoutParams) method in order to get the custom view
centered, simply setting a layout_gravity="center" in the custom view
layout file does not work. Here's a short code snippet showing how I
got it to work:

```
            TextView customView = (TextView)
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom_title_view_centered,
null);
            ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new
ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

            customView.setText("Some centered text");
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customView, params);
```

This method is working for me on at least 3.2, 2.3, and 2.2 devices.

Source https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/A9Ponma6KKI/Llsp41jWLEgJ

Comment: Did you check solutions in the links as well. And , try setting android:layout_width="match_parent" in your RelativeLayout.

Comment: This works, but removes the button for the navigation menu. The ActionBar in Android bloody stinks, so I've always suspected that I'd end up having to roll my own...

Comment: It actually does and is necessary to maintain Androids standard user experience. However once we get familiar to its properties we can use It to suit our needs. Just check if you have set the parent activity to your drawer cause I have used it this way and the drawer icon shows

Comment: this solution does not work if you have overflow icons. overflow icon width does not count for the custom action bar view width, so your centered logo will always be displayed more to the left (as wide as the overflow icons are wide).

Answer (score 4):

First, create a .xml file like this:  (action_bar.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then, in your activity:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);

    TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    Title.setText("Your Title");

getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view,params);       
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //show custom title
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the default title
```

I've tried a lot of solutions and only this one works. Hope it helps you.