# Why wont my action bar text align to the center

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

i'm trying to center my a action bar text.
I've linked the text to my styles.XML, and confirmed this works by changing the font color to red. But when i add android:gravity="center_horizontal", it doesnt seem to work.

My styles.xml code:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

My mainactivity oncreate event:

```
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.tlb_roundedtoolbar))
```

My custom actionbar styling XML file:

```
   [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#fff" />
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>][1]
```

My mainactivity.XML

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tlb_roundedtoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/tlb_roundedtoolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

Here's the result i'm getting with this code:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgFc8.png

**UPDATE**

I've tried placing the toolbar within a linear layout, as suggested in this post: [How to center align the ActionBar title in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android).

However, my current code is still giving me the same result as before, with the text allinging to the left.

Current code (mainactivity.xml):

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlb_roundedtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bcg_rounedrtoolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer to see if it works for you. And if yes, investigate first to see if a solution to your problem has already been published. when you can't find it, ask and say what you tried
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42465266/15351040

Comment: The solution you've linked seems to be in Java, where i'm using kotlin. I've already tried to add android:gravity="center" and center_horizontal in the actionbar styling document and in my mainactivity.xml. I've tried searching for solutions, but all posts i've found reccomend the android:gravity fix, which doesnt seem to be working

Comment: I've posted the code i've used in an update to my original post above