# How to align center action bar tittle

Tags: android

[image]

I know there are two ways of setting the title of activity. One way is the setting it in the android manifest like this android:label="@string/app_name". Second is programmatically setting in activity class like setTitle("Hello World!"). Both ways are positioned in the left side but how can I put it in the center?

Comment: if you used toolbar, then use texttitle appereance

Comment: search on google .what you tried so far ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make android action bar title center aligned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770428/how-to-make-android-action-bar-title-center-aligned)

Comment: you can do this if you are using toolbar:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/7457753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create custom title by adding text view under toolbar like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

call on your activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
mTitle.setText("any");
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: you can use Hitesh method answer below its perfect

Answer (score 1):

Use toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/img_header">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dim_20"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

set theme NotitleBar in manifest file inside activity tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

or

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android Toolbar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**In your `Activity`:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

mTitle.setText("Your Title");

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(""); // Hide default app name
```