# I want to shift application name left side to right side in android & Xamarin

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

Can i right align the application name in android and xamarin

by default the application name is aligned in the left side.

so how to make it aligned it right

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it programmatically. Look the answer of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717159/custom-theme-in-android-xamarin-project-center-title-text-of-action-bar/26737920#26737920)

The only difference is that you will have to set the gravity of the Textview to the right:

```
 modelTitle.Gravity = GravityFlags.Right;
```