# Xamarin forms: Set title text from toolbar in center ( android )

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So i want the title of my toolbar to be centered in Android (like IOS)
I have tried making a renderer but with no success

Thanks in advance

edit:
This is for a toolbar not an actionbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom theme in Android / Xamarin project - center Title text of Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717159/custom-theme-in-android-xamarin-project-center-title-text-of-action-bar)

Comment: @mr deadsven please could you post your renderer code so that we can inspect it.

Comment: The renderer is not working at all, the only thing i do there is find the view of the toolbar and than set the text alignment. But i just found out that the title is set in the contentpage and has nothing to do with that toolbar.

Comment: The dupplicate is an actionbar while i'm talking about a Toolbar. I think these are 2 different things but i'm not sure at all